# Tomcat 7: unable to see home page for tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have downloaded tomcat 7, unzipped it and added it in eclipse. But then i hit the localhost:9999 (my port is 9999), I started the server but the home page for tomcat does not appear. Below is the image:

[image: Browser screen-]

I tried making changes in: D:\java installs\apache-tomcat-7.0\conf\tomcat-users.xml. added user as below:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
  -->
  <!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
  -->
  <!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  -->
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="manager" password="xxxx" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Please help.

Comment: Why did you download a release from 2012 (7.0.34) when there's a current one available (7.0.75, 8.0.41, 8.5.11)? Also: tomcat-users.xml has nothing to do with the deployed webapps. What's in your current webapps folder and what other configuration than the port change did you do?

Comment: @OlafKock i tried with 8.0.41 first but i was getting 404 when i tried to hit localhost:8081.
webapps folder is at default and for configuration change, i am not aware. kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has an option (and AFAIK it's chosen by default) to use the configured tomcat's code, but utilize its (eclipse's) own deployed webapps. This means that you will run tomcat without any webapps if you just start it through eclipse's standard way. You'll have to create a webapplication and deploy it to your tomcat first in order to see it. You won't see tomcat's stock webapp.

So the behavior you see is the expected behavior. If you start tomcat through `bin/startup.bat` it will deploy the stock applications from its `webapps` directory. However, these applications are deployed independently of what you have in `tomcat-users.xml` - this file contains only the usernames/passwords that you can use for quick&dirty setup of the manager application (possibly others). You won't need the manager app if you're working from eclipse, as you'll rather manage the deployed webapplications from the IDE.

However, by all means, when you start downloading Tomcat today, use the latest one, and not a release from 2012. Who knows what issues have been fixed since then, no need to run into them.